# Is it possible to put different structure CSV files into one Parquet file?

Tags: csv, parquet

Generically data follows one XML (ACORD) at a time. There is a process which convert XML into multiple CSV files (around 200+). Is it possible to merge all 200 files into one Parquet file? Or Parquet only supports one CSV structure per file?